# visual intuition for linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that when a transformation is linear, it satisfies the following properties:     $$T(cu+dv) = cT(u) + dT(v)$$

But, Given a arbitrary transformation **T**, and some vectors **u** and **v**. How can we visualize that the transformation is linear, intuitively? What is the visualization of a transformation that is linear, based on the mathematical property.

Comment: If you're looking for intuitive visualizations, I strongly recommend that you watch [this series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjBOesZCoqc&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab) from 3blue1brown

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I did finish the series. And there's one thing missing. The visualization that he gives is that linear transformation is the type with grid lines equally spaced, but that makes less sense with the mathematical definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A linear transformation preserves addition and scalar multiplication. That means if you stretch a vector the image will stretch by the same factor. Preserving the addition means the resultant of two vectors will map to the resultant of the images. Think of projection of a 3 dimensional object on a plane , or taking pictures of an object.The picture of a triangle is a triangle and if you take a picture of two triangles where one is twice the other in size, the picture shows the same proportion.

Comment: This is something that could be added to the video mentioned above.

Comment: Good idea, can you do it?

Comment: Um, I'd like to but, it's not really my video, so ....., sorry.

Comment: But, by far your answer is the one that I understood. I'll just see if I get some more

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to translate the mathematical statement $T(cu + dv) = cT(u) + dT(v)$ into a visualization. Given your vectors $u$ and $v$, imagine a parallelogram grid whose points are $0$, $u$, $v$, $u+v$, $2u$, $2v$, $2u+v$, $2v+u$, $2u+2v$, etc. Upon transformation by $T$, we should get $0$, $T(u)$, $T(v)$, $T(u)+T(v)$, $2T(u)$, etc., i.e., another parallelogram grid (possibly degenerate).

That's one visual characterization of a linear transformation: it transforms a parallelogram grid into a parallelogram grid.

Comment: I think this was mentioned in the video mentioned in the comment above. It's one way to think of it. Still it doesn't give the feel of assurance, like we could predict where the images would land, or atleast vaguely predict the result of a transformation.

Comment: like Mohammad Riazi-Kermani 's statement above. If we stretch the vector, the image will be twice as large.

Comment: @lind "Linear transformation" is a very broad term. We have the same number of degrees of freedom as we have dimensions -- so, in a 2-dimensional space, I could generally map 2 given vectors $u$ and $v$ _anywhere_ and it would still be consistent with some linear transformation. So arbitrary prediction is really impossible.

Comment: @lind However,  once I know where $T(u)$ and $T(v)$ are, that usually determines the transformation. If you're thinking in terms of (2-dimensional) images as Mohammad Riazi-Kermani was discussing, take your image, and pick 2 points: you can map them anywhere. Now consistently stretch, skew, and rotate the image until the two points land at their targets.